# Regexp Replace (as3) - Use text to find but not to replace

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, whitespace

Having some trouble with regexp. My XML file loaded to actionscript removes all spaces (automatically trims the text). So I want to replace all SPACE with a word so that I can fix that later on in my own parsing.

Here's examples of how the tags I want to adjust.

```
<w:t> </w:t>
<w:t> Test</w:t>
<w:t>Test </w:t>
```

This is the result I want.

```
<w:t>%SPACE%</w:t>
<w:t>%SPACE%Test</w:t>
<w:t>Test%SPACE%</w:t>
```

The closest result I got is `<w:t>\s|\s</w:t>`

Biggest problem is that it changes all spaces in the XML file that corrupts everything. Will only change inside w:t nodes but not destroy the text.

Comment: How about `<w:t> Test Test </w:t>`? Should all three spaces be replaced?

Answer (score 1):

```
var reg1 : RegExp = /((?:<w:t>|\G)[^<\s]*+)\s/g;
data = data.replace(reg1, "$1%SPACE%");
```

`(?:<w:t>|\G)` means every match starts at a `<w:t>` tag, **or** immediately after the previous match.  Since `[^<\s]` can't match the closing `</w:t>` tag (or any other tag), every match is guaranteed to be inside a `<w:t>` element.

To do this properly, you would need to deal with some more questions, like:

- `\s` matches several other kinds of whitespace, not just `' '`.  Do you want to replace **any** whitespace character with `%SPACE%`?  Or do you know that `' '` will be the only kind of whitespace in those elements?
- Will there be other elements inside the `<w:t>` elements (for example, `<w:t> test <xyz> test </xyz> </w:t>`)?  If so, the regex becomes more complicated, but it's still doable.

I'm not set up to test ActionScript, but here's a demo in PHP, which uses the PCRE library under the hood, like AS3:
**[test it on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/prQSf)**

EDIT: In addition to matching where the last match left off, `\G` matches the beginning of the input, just like `\A`.  That's not a problem with the regex given here, but in the ideone demo it is.  That regex should be

```
((?:<w:t>|\G(?!\A))(?:[^<\s]++|<(?!/w:t>))*+)\s
```

Answer (score 1):

When parsing XML using the standard [`XML`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html) class in ActionScript you can specify to not ignore whitespace by setting the [`ignoreWhiteSpace`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#ignoreWhitespace) property to `false`. It is set to `true` by default. This will ensure that white space in XML text nodes is preserved. You can then do whatever you want with it.

```
XML.ignoreWhiteSpace = false
/* parse your XML here */
```

That way you don't have to muck around with regular expressions and can use the standard XML ActionScript parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Made a workaround that isn't so nice. But well, problem is when you work against the clock.

I run the replace 3 times instead.

```
var reg1 : RegExp = /<w:t>\s/gm;
data = data.replace(reg1, "<w:t>%DEADSPACE%");

var reg2 :RegExp = /\s<\/w:t>/gm;
data = data.replace(reg2, "%DEADSPACE%</w:t>");

var reg3 :RegExp = /<w:t>\s<\/w:t>/gm;
data = data.replace(reg3, "<w:t>%DEADSPACE%</w:t>");
```

RegExp, what is it good for. Absolutly nothing (singing) ;)

Comment: Regex is good for quite a lot if you use it properly. It just takes practice. (I'm not trying to come off as condescending, just stating a fact. Took me months to really get good at them!)

Answer (score 0):

[there's also another way](http://wonderfl.net/c/naqG/read)